# Extract data from JSON API using Python 2.7

Tags: python, json

**This is my php code**
php code work fine

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://examole.com/api.php');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($obj as $row)
{
       echo ( $row["first_name"] );

       echo "<br>";
}
```

**This is my python code**

```
from urllib import urlopen
import simplejson as json

url=urlopen('http://examole.com/api.php')
result = json.loads(url)
print utl.get('first_name').get('data')
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Also attach a sample JSON that you are trying to parse

Comment: python file not work i get
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
this error

Comment: Then there is some issue with the http://examole.com/api.php

Comment: how to solve this problem

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you didn't use the object you loaded from JSON text.
You should try this

```
data = result.get("first_name").get("data")
```